# Find closest positive value based on multiple criteria

Tags: postgresql, join, vlookup

First of all I am still learning `sql / postgresql` so I am eagerly looking for explanations and thought process / strategy instead of just the raw answer. And I apologize in advance for the potential future misunderstandings or "stupid" questions.

Also if you know a great site which propose exercices or challenges in order to master `sql / postgresql`, I take everything :)

I am looking for a way to return the closest value, based on other specific results in the same table.

In the same table, I am tracking different events:

- `ESESS` = End session event. Gives me a new timestamp (ts) every time Georges (id) finishes a session (let's say Georges is using a computer, so end session = shut the computer down)
- `USD` = Amount of money inventory update event. Each time Georges spends/earn money, those 3 columns will return me the new balance (v), as well as his id and timestamp (ts) when the balance has been updated.

What I am trying to get is the balance at the end of each session.

My plan was to return esess.id and usd.v only if (ts.esess - ts.usd) is equal to the smallest minimum positive value.
So some sort of lookup from the ts.usd, when (ts.esess - ts.usd) match the condition...but I'm struggling with that part.

Here is the strategy in the following link:
[QUERY PLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uVFY.jpg)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
      sessId, moneyV
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ts as sessTs,
        mid as sessId
      FROM
        table1
      WHERE
        n='esess'
    ) as sess
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        ts as moneyTs,
        mid as moneyId,
        v as moneyV
      FROM
        table1
      WHERE
        n='usd'
    )as balance
    ON sessId = moneyId
    WHERE
      sessTs - moneyTs =
      (
        SELECT 
          sessTs - moneyTs as timeDiff
        FROM
          table1
        WHERE
          sessTs - moneyTs > 0
        ORDER BY
          timeDiff ASC
        LIMIT 1
      )
;
```

So how should I proceed?

Also, I dug to find answers and find [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73804/how-to-retrieve-closest-value-based-on-look-up-table) in particular, but did not understand everything and did not manage to make it work properly...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody? Not even a hint?